# To user Tasklet or Chunk in this scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a job/task to `read sub-folders/directory` of a `given folder/path`. The path is dynamic, we get it from `Controller`. Currently, I have used `Tasklet`, there are 3 tasklets, one to read sub-directories, another to process it to prepare objects to save to DB and last one to write the processed data objects to a database.
The folders can have any number of sub-folders.Currently, I have used this code :

```
 Path start = Paths.get("x:\\data\\");
    Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(start, 1);
List<String> collect = stream
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To read all the sub folders at once.
I followed this `https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk` example of `Tasklet` implementation for the purpose. Is this the right approach ? I also need to run the Job asynchronously with multi-threading.
As there can be huge numbers of sub-folders, `so there can be huge number of` rows`or`list `of data to process and write to the database.`

Please suggest an appropriate approach.
I am learning `Spring Batch`, have done few examples on `file read/process/write` too and used `Chunk` approach for this.
But my job is to read sub-directories of a folder/path, so I cannot decide which approach to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar scenario: I need to read all the files from a folder, process and write in db, ([Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html))

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

@Bean
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
               Step masterStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("MainJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(masterStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step mainStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                     JdbcBatchItemWriter<Transaction> writer,
                     ItemReader<String> reader,
                     TransactionItemProcessor processor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("Main")
            .<String, Transaction>chunk(2)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            **.taskExecutor(jobTaskExecutor())**
            .listener(new ItemReaderListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<String> reader(@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) throws IOException {
    Path start = Paths.get("D:\\test");
    List<String> inputFile = Files.walk(start, 1)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new IteratorItemReader<>(inputFile);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public TransactionItemProcessor processor(@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) {

    return new TransactionItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Transaction> writer(DataSource dataSource) {

    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Transaction>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO transaction (id, date, type) VALUES (:id, :date, :type)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
}
```

}

Comment: ,Thank you for the reply. In my context, I only need to get the path of the sub folder, no need to read the files. For example, main folder = //a and there are sub-folders /a/b, /a/c, /a/d,.,etc and create list of objects contain the parent path and sub folder path to save to DB. So my question is if I follow your approach, will it read all the subfolders at once or chunk by chunk ? Your example is a Chunk based approach.If we would like to do it in Tasklet approach, how would it be ? Can you modify the example for just reading the path as in my code snippet with reader also included?

Comment: After doing some testing,  I think the best approach is with chunks, I edited the code . Adding the TaskExecutor allows you to add multithreading, and if you want a better performance you can check the remote chunking. I edited the code

Comment: where is the `TaskExecutor`  set ?

Comment: in the mainStep